# SMS: AT commands

Tags: sms

I am trying to set up an SMS gateway on my computer

here's some code I found:

```
AT
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","+85291234567",,"06/11/11,00:30:29+32"
Hello, welcome to our SMS tutorial.
+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","+85291234567",,"06/11/11,00:32:20+32"
A simple demo of SMS text messaging.

OK
```

can this be done in windows?

what steps do I have to take in order to set this up?

what is the compiler?

how do I get started?

Comment: The page you seem to have found that example ( [Short Message Service / SMS Tutorial](http://www.developershome.com/sms/) ) has extensive information on how to use SMS commands. Your questions are answered within that tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_phone_AT_commands), which are used with modems (or cell phones) who support that interface.

If you cell phone is connected to your computer by serial, you can open a HyperTerminal/Telnet/etc and communicate with it via AT commands.

There is no compiler or such, as this is merely a protocol for communicating with supporting devices.