# getting started with SMS developement

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

i will have the following set up:

people will be sending text messages to a server, and that server will be forwarding the messages to other phone numbers

i am not sure what kind of framework i should use.

1. should i develop an SMS gateway and use AT commands?
2. should i just try to somehow use AIM or GCHAT to capture and send SMS messages?
3. would there be a different more suitable configuration?

are there already developed frameworks that are free which i can use? for example i know that i can send an SMS to almost anyone through gchat or aim by sending a message to "+" and the number of the person. is this scalable and can i use it for my own benefit?

any sms developers out there?

Comment: Have you read the tutorial referenced in your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994118/sms-at-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use this website: [www.aspsms.com](http://www.aspsms.com).

It provides a lot of libraries in different languages, the prices are affordable (I think) and  they offer some kind of "2 ways service".

> are there already developed frameworks that are free which i can use?

Free, that would surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a [short cod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code)e from an aggregator like www.openmarket.com