# connecting cell phone to computer

Tags: .net, c++, sms

is it possible for me to intercept the text messages that get sent to my cellphone if i connect to my cellphone via bluetooth or USB or some other connection to my computer?

i want to create a database with all of my received text messages and be able to control my cell phone through my computer by using it to send text messages

i have a regular motorola flip phone

Comment: What OS does the cell phone use? The answer will vary somewhere between yes and no, depending on the platforms you'd like to support

Comment: Somebody asked a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994180/getting-started-with-sms-developement Follow the links and there's an extensive tutorial on the web that looks really informative.

Comment: it doesnt matter to me, its a motorala phone with TMOBILE on it, is there a different OS that you recommend? preferably a cheap phone please

Comment: greg, you follow it, its not so h elpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GSM Specification 27.005](http://www.arib.or.jp/IMT-2000/V710Dec08/5_Appendix/R99/27/27005-320.pdf) you should be able to get indication on incoming sms.

You need to open AT Command terminal to the phone (most of the times you do that by plugging the phone to the usb, and connect to the com port that was created for it).

The command that you are looking for is AT+CNMI. Just read the specification.

NOTE: Long time ago, I've tried to do the same thing using Nokia phone and it didn't work. The phone didn't support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can send text messages from your phone to your email address, and email messages to your phone number. I'm not sure if you could "intercept" the messages, but you could set up a smart mailbox that catches all emails with a certain tag or from a certain sender (your phone number).

Answer (score 1):

look into a program/app called PDANet.
It allows you to connect via USB and have text message displayed (and you can respond to them also) on your computer.

However, I don't know if this will allow you to archive them though.

Comment: thank you for trying to help but this is for android only and does not do what i requested in question